# Convert this into polar form?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$(\sqrt{3+i})^{50}\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{where }i^2=-1$$

Here first I tried by multiplying it with $2^25$ or $4^25$ Because we want it in that form but couldn't simplify it further. Also 
$$(3+i)^{25} = (3+i)(3+i)^{24}= (3+i)(8+6i)^{12} = 2^{12} (3+i)(4+3i)^{12}$$
On doing these continuously so that we get the form $x+iy$ and then directly converting it into polar form.
But still I haven't got the answer because on doing this continously  x+iy form gets too large and I was unable to take 2^25 or 4^25 common.
Could someone help.
Different method other than this would be appreciated.

Comment: the question instructs you to use the polar form. follow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First turn $3+i$ into polar form. Its norm is $\sqrt{10}$ and its argument $t$ satisfies $\tan(t)=1/3$ and it is in the first quadrant. So, $$3+i=\sqrt{10}e^{it}.$$

Now we compute $$\sqrt{3+i}=10^{1/4}e^{it/2+k\pi}, \qquad \text{ for }k=0,1.$$

Now we raise this to the $50$

$$(\sqrt{3+i})^{50}=10^{50/4}e^{50it/2+50k\pi}=10^{25/2}e^{25it}$$

> **Moral:** Exponentials are easier in polar form; as are multiplications and logarithms.

Comment: What's your answer according to options ?

Comment: What do you mean by "according to options"?

Comment: @Pp.. I believe you can say "Exponentials are easier in polar form, as are multiplications and logarithms" Or "Exponentials are easier in polar form, as are terms involving multiplication and logarithms" ;)

Comment: Good. I tried: "as they are", "as so are", "as they also are".

Comment: First edit had a photo which had options for this questions

Comment: @MurtuzaVadharia Ah! That was a multiple choice question? I think none of the options is good.

Comment: option are                                 (a)4^25 cos pi/6 + i sin pi/6)                (b) 2^50 (cos pi/3 + i sin pi/3)               (c) 3^50 (cos pi/6 + i  sin pi/6)               (d) 2^25 ( cos pi/4 + i  sin pi/4)

Comment: @MurtuzaVadharia Oh answer is a. But wait it can be b, or maybe c.